# Can I use AcceptButton() to move to the next textbox?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a simple login screen and I have already implemented a simple method in the password textbox to simulate the 'OK" button being clicked:

```
private void textpwd_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = btnLogin;
}
```

can I use the same method in the username textbox to move to the password textbox?

```
private void textusername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = textpassword.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Users usually press tab to switch to the next text box..

Comment: yeah I know that. But sometimes when logging in somewhere some people press enter to go to the next textbox.

Comment: what is acceptbutton  ? Is it third party button or the button you created in your page ? because you have created tag for acceptbutton

Comment: `AcceptButtion` is a function that simulates the Enter or Return button being pressed in a text field.

Comment: Focus() returns bool value and can assign bool to AcceptButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textusername_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        textpassword.Focus(); // or SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to write a specific code for each of your `TextBox`(es) it's better to simulate the `Tab` key press behavior.

1. Edit the Tab order via `View` -> `TabOrder` based on your needs.
2. Set the following method for all of your form controls `KeyDown` event

   ```
   private void AllControls_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
           SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
           e.SuppressKeyPress = true;                
       }
   }
   ```